# How to create SliverAppBar with bottom

Tags: flutter, user-interface

How to create SliverAppBar with bottom like this example:
[SliverAppBar MGM Resort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFI0s.gif)

Comment: Try to implement your own SliverPersistentHeader via SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate. This video nicely and briefly show its implementation for custom SliverAppBar. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3-WdYBrEDc . I also needed to create custom SliverAppBar and was able to achieve that with this. In your case, you need to calculate borders, and some positions only based on AppBar offset as shown in video.

Comment: Thanks! Try to implement